# Stored Procedure with join returning multiple records

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_RandomisationResultCount]
    @noOfRows INT,
    @subcouncil INT,
    @wards VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @suburbs VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @courts VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @skills VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @isDisabled VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
    @hasQualification VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
    @gender VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
    @age INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        COUNT(tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID) resultCount
    FROM 
        tblJobSeekerDetails 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_lnk_JobSeeker_OtherSkills ON tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID = tbl_lnk_JobSeeker_OtherSkills.JobSeeker_ID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblOtherSkills ON tbl_lnk_JobSeeker_OtherSkills.OtherSkillsID = tblOtherSkills.OtherSkillsID 
    /*LEFT JOIN tblJobSeekerEmploymentHistory
    ON tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID = tblJobSeekerEmploymentHistory.JobSeekerID*/
    WHERE 
        (tblJobSeekerDetails.SubCouncilID = @subcouncil)
        AND ((WardID IN (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@wards, ',') s)) OR (@wards IS NULL))
        AND ((Suburb IN (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@suburbs, ',') s)) OR (@suburbs IS NULL))
        AND ((RoadType IN (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@courts, ',') s)) OR (@courts IS NULL))
        AND ((tblOtherSkills.OtherSkillsID in (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@skills, ',') s)) OR (@skills IS NULL))
        AND ((Disability = @isDisabled) OR (@isDisabled IS NULL))
        AND ((HasTertiaryQualification = @hasQualification) OR (@hasQualification IS NULL))
        AND ((Gender = @gender) OR (@gender IS NULL))
        AND ((ISNUMERIC(IdentityNumber) = 1 AND 
              IdentityNumber NOT LIKE '%.%' AND 
              DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - (CONVERT(INT, '19' + SUBSTRING(IdentityNumber, 1, 2), 100)) = @age) OR (@age IS NULL))
        AND (TypeID = 1)--Jobseekers only
        AND (tblJobSeekerDetails.IsExcludedFromRandomisation <> 1 OR tblJobSeekerDetails.IsExcludedFromRandomisation IS NULL)--Explicitly excluded jobseekers
        AND (tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT tj.JobSeeker_ID --Exclude Jobseekers as per stipulated exclusion periods
                                                      FROM tblJobSeekerDetails tj INNER JOIN tblJobSeekerEmploymentHistory wh
                                                      ON tj.JobSeeker_ID = wh.JobSeekerID
                                                      WHERE ((DATEDIFF(DAY, wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo) <= 14 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo, GETDATE()) <= 3 ))
                                                      OR
                                                      ((DATEDIFF(DAY, wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo) > 14 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo, GETDATE()) <= 6))
                                                      OR
                                                      (GETDATE() BETWEEN wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom AND wh.DateOfEmploymentTo)
                                                      OR (wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom > GETDATE() OR wh.DateOfEmploymentTo > GETDATE())
                                                      GROUP BY tj.JobSeeker_ID))
        AND (tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT te.JobSeeker_ID -- Exclude jobseekers that were recently availed to a project
                                                      FROM tblJobSeekerDetails te INNER JOIN tbl_RandomisedJobseeker rj
                                                      ON te.JobSeeker_ID = rj.JobseekerID
                                                      WHERE (GETDATE() < rj.ExcludedTo)
                                                      GROUP BY te.JobSeeker_ID))
END
```

This stored procedure returns multiple records for jobseekers that have more than one "OtherSkills". I need to modify it so that it only returns one. I presume this is due to the join. Yet, I cant just return the first "OtherSkill". I need all the skills for a given jobseeker so that I can compare it with the criteria that is received.

(I just started considering the possibility to make use of a table variable. Sometimes writing out a question really helps :))

Comment: How do you want to have all skills returned in one row?

Comment: @Szymon: Not exactly sure. I was thinking about putting them all into a table variable and using this in the stored procedure. Problem is, there will be a lot of records in this variable. Over 500k at least

Comment: And, with this, I have no idea how to compare the skills for only the given jobseeker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making use of the `WITH` clause to load all the data from the jobseeker table that I need to filter on to do my counting. I also do the filtering for the skills in this `WITH`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_RandomisationResultCount]
    @noOfRows INT,
    @subcouncil INT,
    @wards VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @suburbs VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @courts VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @skills VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @isDisabled VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
    @hasQualification VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
    @gender VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
    @age INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    WITH JobSeekerDetails AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT jsd.JobSeeker_ID,
                        jsd.SubCouncilID,
                        jsd.WardID,
                        jsd.Suburb,
                        jsd.RoadType,
                        jsd.Disability,
                        jsd.HasTertiaryQualification,
                        jsd.Gender,
                        jsd.IdentityNumber,
                        jsd.TypeID,
                        jsd.IsExcludedFromRandomisation
        FROM dbo.tblJobSeekerDetails jsd
        LEFT JOIN tbl_lnk_JobSeeker_OtherSkills jos
        ON jsd.JobSeeker_ID = jsd.JobSeeker_ID
        LEFT JOIN tblOtherSkills os
        ON jos.OtherSkillsID = os.OtherSkillsID
        WHERE ((os.OtherSkillsID in (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@skills, ',') s)) OR (@skills IS NULL))
    )

    SELECT COUNT(jsd.JobSeeker_ID) resultCount
    FROM tblJobSeekerDetails jsd
    INNER JOIN JobSeekerDetails
    ON jsd.JobSeeker_ID = JobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID
    WHERE (jsd.SubCouncilID = @subcouncil)
        AND ((jsd.WardID IN (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@wards, ',') s)) OR (@wards IS NULL))
        AND ((jsd.Suburb IN (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@suburbs, ',') s)) OR (@suburbs IS NULL))
        AND ((jsd.RoadType IN (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@courts, ',') s)) OR (@courts IS NULL))
        AND ((jsd.Disability = @isDisabled) OR (@isDisabled IS NULL))
        AND ((jsd.HasTertiaryQualification = @hasQualification) OR (@hasQualification IS NULL))
        AND ((jsd.Gender = @gender) OR (@gender IS NULL))
        AND ((ISNUMERIC(jsd.IdentityNumber) = 1 AND 
              jsd.IdentityNumber NOT LIKE '%.%' AND 
              DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - (CONVERT(INT, '19' + SUBSTRING(jsd.IdentityNumber, 1, 2), 100)) = @age) OR (@age IS NULL))
        AND (jsd.TypeID = 1)--Jobseekers only
        AND (jsd.IsExcludedFromRandomisation <> 1 OR jsd.IsExcludedFromRandomisation IS NULL)--Explicitly excluded jobseekers
        AND (jsd.JobSeeker_ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT tj.JobSeeker_ID --Exclude Jobseekers as per stipulated exclusion period
                                      FROM tblJobSeekerDetails tj
                                      INNER JOIN tblJobSeekerEmploymentHistory wh
                                      ON tj.JobSeeker_ID = wh.JobSeekerID
                                      WHERE ((DATEDIFF(DAY, wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo) <= 14 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo, GETDATE()) <= 3 ))
                                      OR
                                      ((DATEDIFF(DAY, wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo) > 14 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo, GETDATE()) <= 6))
                                      OR
                                      (GETDATE() BETWEEN wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom AND wh.DateOfEmploymentTo)
                                      OR (wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom > GETDATE() OR wh.DateOfEmploymentTo > GETDATE())
                                      GROUP BY tj.JobSeeker_ID))
        AND (jsd.JobSeeker_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT te.JobSeeker_ID -- Exclude jobseekers that were recently availed to a project
                                      FROM tblJobSeekerDetails te INNER JOIN tbl_RandomisedJobseeker rj
                                      ON te.JobSeeker_ID = rj.JobseekerID
                                      WHERE (GETDATE() < rj.ExcludedTo)
                                      GROUP BY te.JobSeeker_ID))
END
```